# how to obfuscate android apk

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

hi i want obfuscate my apk but when i use **minifyEnabled true** my app crash in release mode, so i updated my as to 3.4.2 and i realized that there is a new system called R8 I have activated it, but my code is still readable

things i did

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
```

and in gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.enableR8 = true
```

After the release apk, the code is visible by the jadx program
I am confused now, can someone tell me how to obfuscate apk?
[image]

Comment: _"there is a new system called R8 I have activated it"_ What you've done is turn off shrinking and obfuscation. R8 is a rop-in replacement for ProGuard, so you still need to have `minifyEnabled true`. The `android.enableR8` can be used to say that you still want to use ProGuard for minification instead of R8, by setting it to `false` (it is `true` by default). The `useProguard` property is now deprecated. If `minifyEnabled true` causes your app to crash, then the proper solution is to fix those crashes. Start by analyzing the stack traces.

Comment: @Michael tnx You explained to me perfectly, just one more question, this line should be deleted or not?             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open `proguard-rules.pro` for editing and add this:

```
# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

This will rename all of the classes to an unreadable format.

Answer (score 6):

Given the fact that proguard offers trivial obfuscation techniques (it is an optimizer) we have developed an APK obfuscator, check it out:

https://github.com/ClaudiuGeorgiu/Obfuscapk

Answer (score 2):

On Android Gradle Plugin 3.4, to enable R8 you just set minifyEnabled to true. It looks like you have it set to false, which disables both ProGuard and R8. R8 is the default shrinker in 3.4, so you don’t need any settings other than minifyEnabled to enable it.